# Looking for a simple JSON data admin interface

Tags: cms, json

I've just built a website for myself where all the content is in JSON files. I was wondering if there's some really simple server-side tool that will let me surf to a URL where I can edit the content of these JSON files (rather than SFTP in and edit them manually).

In other words, I would go to `http://mysite.com/admin`, log in (maybe just something simple like HTTP DIGEST), and then be able to view a list of JSON files and click a button to edit the content. Ideally it would parse the data and arrays into a format that would make it easy to edit as well as add new entries.

So in essence this is a CMS for web dev geeks. :) Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What programming languages does your server support?

Comment: PHP, Perl. Maybe Ruby?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you well, you're looking for something like [JSONmate](http://jsonmate.com).

You can edit the JSON in various ways:

- like a text file:

  [image: text JSON presentation]
- with a prettier presentation:

  [image: graphical JSON presentation]

As a bonus, you also have a graph representation of your JSON architecture:

[image: JSON presentation as graph]

Comment: Very cool looking! But I don't see any server side code in the Github repo. I need something that actually saves/updates the JSON file on the server.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack If you have a way to store json objects on your server, you just need to update the server-side json with the rencently-modified json (not the most difficult task ever :). I'll tell you if I find something closer to your needs.

Comment: Right! Basically just a PHP script or something that reads a JSON file, makes a nice spiffy interface for it which lets me make changes and add new entries maybe, then save it back to disk. Heck, I'll probably just wind up writing one. I just wanted to make sure something didn't already exist that fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

One tool that can do this is [FrontAid CMS](https://frontaid.io/). Essentially, it uses your Git repository as a database for JSON content. Then you can open FrontAid and update those file(s) which are stored directly into Git again. So you always have your complete content available in a version-controlled JSON file in your own Git repository.

Depending on your setup, you might need to rebuild your website/application whenever content is updated. You can easily automate that with Git Hooks and/or CI/CD tools.

Disclaimer: I work at FrontAid.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [JSONView Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) to view JSON on server. Editing is not supported though.

Comment: Editing is a core requirement of the question.